# Never-ending game with two players?

Tags: balance, little-dungeon

The Shadow Mage is summoned once one player uses his entire hand. However, in the vast majority of two-player games I have played we get so stocked up on weapons, shields, and treasure that we become invincible and never run out of cards.

We usually just summon the Shadow Mage once the deck pile is emptied out to get the game over-with.

Is this game properly balanced for two-players?